# What's the word for "to say fondly"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there as word that means "to say fondly"?
I've searched far and wide, but I have not located an adequate word. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks so very much.

-Kelsey

Answer (score 2):

If the verb is intended to introduce something said tenderly, endearingly, softly, a nice word could be [coo](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/coo):

- to speak in a soft, gentle, or loving way:

*[+ speech] "How wonderful to see you again, darling," she **cooed**.*

*[with direct speech] ‘‘I knew I could count on you,’ she **cooed**.* (Source: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coo)

The verb can also be used within a sentence to mean "to speak fondly about something," as in:

- The family cooed over the baby pictures. (Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coo)